# does 3.x Spark on Kubernetes (K8s) support task logs in the Spark UI?

Tags: apache-spark

The "Logs" tab for tasks seems to be missing in the Spark UI. Does Spark version 3.x on Kubernetes (K8s) support the display of task logs in the Spark UI?